# Get subcategories after drop down box selection in wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I currently have a dropdown box which contains a list of all of the different categories on my website, and I need to add a sub-categories box underneath it. So far, I have this code:

```
    wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none='.__('Select one','appthemes').'&class=dropdownlist&orderby=name&order=ASC&hide_empty=0&hierarchical=1&taxonomy=ad_cat&depth=1&name=preselect');

   wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none='.__('Select one','appthemes').'&class=dropdownlist&orderby=name&order=ASC&hide_empty=0&hierarchical=1&taxonomy=ad_cat&child_of=6');
```

The 2nd line of code finds all of the sub-categories that belong to the main category with the ID no. 6. How would I automatically change the no.6 when the first drop down box is changed? E.g. if I select ID 7 from the dropdown box, I need the subcategories for ID 7 to show instead of ID 6.

Thanks for any help

Edit: I am trying to run a function after one of the drop down options is chosen, could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
$('#cat').click(function() {

alert("test");

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with Javascript. Add a `onchange` attribute to the first dropdown and load the contents of the second dropdown via Ajax.

Comment: Thanks cweiske, I'll give it a try. I'm not sure how to edit functions like this in wordpress so I'm trying to do it via Jquery, do you know what I'm doing wrong in my edited question?

Answer (score 1):

Daniel you could use this tutorial to get you started:

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/implement-ajax-wordpress-themes/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too many items you may want to filter client side instead of making wordpress run a new query everytime.

You could also trigger the second dropdown by setting the 'id' attribute of the first dropdown's rows to the number you wanted and on click/hover you can filter via the ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
                $orderby = 'name';
                            $show_count = 0; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
                            $pad_counts = 0; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
                            $hierarchical = 1; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
                            $taxonomy = 'portfolio_category';
                            $title = '';


                    if( $terms = get_terms( array( 'child_of' => 39,
                                              'orderby' => $orderby,
                                              'show_count' => $show_count,
                                              'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
                                              'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                                              'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                                              'depth'    => 2,
                                              'hide_empty' => 0 ) ) ) : 

                        echo '<select class="techno-portfolio" name="categoryfilter"><option value="">Select technology</option>';
                        foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
                            echo '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>'; // ID of the category as the value of an option
                        ;
                        endforeach;
                        echo '</select>';
                    endif;
                ?>
```

Use the above code to show the sub-category of main category inside drop-down the 39 is the category ID which subcategory you need to show in dropdown.